# Request deletion of spam account

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

So this is a [blatant spam account](https://askubuntu.com/users/151381/socanpower). The profile description is spam and the profile pic is that of a pretty girl, probably taken without the consent of the owner. Only post is blatant spam. The issue with spam accounts was discussed [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6317/should-spam-only-accounts-always-be-deleted). So should this account be deleted?

Comment: This was also discussed in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9104254#9104254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What account are you talking about?

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
(Commercial Song starts!)

**TROLL!!**

Because there's always one with us!

(Commercial Song stops!)

NOTE - BTW I Deleted the account and yeah it was spam.

Ad brought to you by the Spaminator!