# Should this account be deleted?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I recently asked for [a clear spam account to be deleted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6576/request-deletion-of-spam-account). It subsequently was, but now there is a different issue with a different user. This time there is an unregistered account that is just trolling a [particular question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284722/how-do-i-remove-this-annoyingly-pixelated-popup/284765#284765). Is it enough to admonish the person doing this or should his [unregistered account](https://askubuntu.com/users/151630/loraag) be deleted? His answer poses a threat to users at the very least.

---

Original post:

> sudo rm -rf /
>
> proven to work everytime

---

Comments:

> That's the spirit.
>
> I wish I had a cat in my hat.

Comment: Took care of him. Thanks Nil.

Comment: I wish that those comments were the *complete* list of comments created by the user, but unfortunately there weren't..

Answer (score 1):

Account deletion is a serious proceeding and needs to be used and thought of as such. Deleting a spam account is *very* different from deleting a *real person's* account, whether they were trolling or whatever. Everyone gets a little put out at times, and while that isn't an excuse for being rude (or whatever etc, etc) it certainly isn't a reason for *deleting* anyone's account.

If the issue was as serious as you make it out to be the moderators will probably talk to him, and if he continues he'll probably get banned.

You mention that the account is an unregistered one. All that means is that the person never approved an email. Not much to go by ;-)